# Purpose of Star Icon on Trading

Tags: no-mans-sky

I've noticed that on occasion while browsing items for trade that an item will have a star icon on its listing.  Does anyone know what it means?  From what I can tell the icon has no influence on the worth of the item nor does it influence whether it is trading above or below market.  Does it denote an item that I need?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it is a gold/yellow star in a circle, it denotes the price being nearly double (or half) of its usual value. If the price is green, this is a good thing, and if it's red, you should probably avoid buying/selling at that price unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: It should be noted that you still need to take care of the actual prince and not just trust the star icon. Suspension Fluid sells for about ~2k Units but when you buy it the price is above 20k Units.

Comment: @udondan I think that is a bug specific to Suspension Fluid though. (Not 100% sure on that, but I've never seen any other items with that huge of a  price gap.)

Comment: I also think it's a bug. One that cost me 400k before i noticed it because I bought/sold every green listed item. :D

Comment: atlas stones sell for 60k, purchase for 2.5 mil

Answer (score 1):

The star is an indicator of high demand for that item - the trader will pay around twice the usual price for it (usually +90% to +110% on the selling screen).

Comment: It could also be an extreme lack of demand, though.

Answer (score -1):

This Icon Represents items that are at a higher value than they usually would be, which means you can get offered more units when selling them or be charged more if you are after purchasing them.